# Compilation error with ENUM class

Tags: java

sorry for asking such basic question. I am trying some hands on ENUM. below is my code. I am getting some compilation error   . Any idea where is the problem. I want SAMPLEMAIL,BULKUSERS,ALLUSERS should be of integer type.

```
 public enum EmailSendingOption {

        SAMPLEMAIL, BULKUSERS, ALLUSERS;

        private int emailSendingOptionType;

        private EmailSendingOption(String optionType) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(optionType.trim());
            emailSendingOptionType = value;
        }

        public int getEmailSendingOption() {
            return emailSendingOptionType;
        }

    }
```

thanks.

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: `enum` are not integers in Java, they are objects.

Comment: Constructor EmailSendingOption in enum EmailSendingOption cannot be applied to given types. required: String , found: no arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum` are not integers in Java, they are objects. There is no sane reason you would pass an integer as a String to a constructor so it can be parsed into an integer. If you want an integer use an integer.

```
public enum EmailSendingOption {

    SAMPLEMAIL(1), BULKUSERS(2), ALLUSERS(101);

    private final int emailSendingOptionType;

    private EmailSendingOption(int emailSendingOptionType) {
        this.emailSendingOptionType = emailSendingOptionType;
    }

    public int getEmailSendingOption() {
        return emailSendingOptionType;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined a constructor but you haven't supplied arguments for each of your Enums.

Looks like your constructor should take an integer too. Saves having to parse a String each time. It's also safer.

e.g.

`SAMPLEMAIL(10)`, etc.

With your constructor looking like:

```
private int emailSendingOptionType;

private EmailSendingOption(int optionType) {
  this.emailSendingOptionType = optionType;
}
```

Comment: +1. A minor correction `SAMPLEMAIL(10)`  should be `SAMPLEMAIL("10")`

Comment: As it stands, yes, but if you look closely, he's taking a String as a parameter in the constructor, then parsing it to an int. Would be best to just change the constructor to take an int.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it like this:

```
public enum EmailSendingOption {

    SAMPLEMAIL("1"), BULKUSERS("2"), ALLUSERS("3");

    private int emailSendingOptionType;

    private EmailSendingOption(String optionType) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(optionType.trim());
        emailSendingOptionType = value;
    }

    public int getEmailSendingOption() {
        return emailSendingOptionType;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are  providing a custom constructor to your `Enum`

```
EmailSendingOption(String optionType)
```

You need to add those parameter for each Enum constant.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
public enum EmailSendingOption 
  {

            SAMPLEMAIL("String"), BULKUSERS("String"), ALLUSERS("String");
    ...
  }
```

You defined a constructor as needed a String as argument. SAMPLEMAIL this are a static object
of EmailSendingOption.